# Did Turkey use poison gas against the Kurds in 1937-38?

Tags: history, war, turkey, kurds

Baki Tezcan
[writes](https://www.latimes.com/opinion/story/2019-10-17/turkey-kurds-syria-invasion-ceasefire-erdogan) in an LA Times opinion piece:

> In the 1920s and ’30s, Kurdish citizens of Turkey were brutally massacred in military responses to rebellions. Those uprisings were also conveniently used by the ruling regime to suppress political opposition and further consolidate the single-party system. In the most savage case, **Turkish security forces used aerial bombings and mass executions, *and in some instances poisonous gas,* against Kurdish civilians in the 1937-38 rebellion in the Dersim region.** Many of the survivors were moved to other parts of Turkey and Kurdish girls were given to urban Turkish families for adoption.

I see however that Wikipedia is much more reserved about this, [stating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dersim_rebellion) only that

> Nuri Dersimi claimed that the Turkish air force bombed the district with poisonous gas in 1938.

(Dersimi is a Kurdish writer.) So what evidence is there for the claim that Turkey used gas against the Kurds in the late 1930s?

Comment: It's worth noting that most political topics on Wikipedia are highly manipulated by interested parties. I would imagine that Turkey probably has people monitoring this stuff, while the Kurds probably do not.